# How to show UIImageview animation when added to a UIView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiimageview

I am trying to create a custom view which saves all the UIImage's in an array and then assign this array to animationImages property of UIImageView.

But the problem is this works fine if I do this inside the UIViewController where I want this however when I am trying to create this through a custom UIView its not displaying anything.

Here's my code:

```
@interface IndicatorView : UIView

@property(nonatomic, strong) UIImageView * indicatorView;
-(void)createIndicator;
-(void)startAnimating;
-(void)stopAnimating;

@end

#import "ConfIndicatorView.h"

@implementation ConfIndicatorView


- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        [self createIndicator];

    }
    return self;
}


-(void)createIndicator
{
    NSArray * imageArray  = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"spinner-1.png"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"spinner-2.png"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"spinner-3.png"],
                             nil];
    _indicatorView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];
    _indicatorView.animationImages = imageArray;
    _indicatorView.animationDuration = 1.0f;
    _indicatorView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
[self addSubview:_indicatorView];
    [_indicatorView startAnimating];// Just added this to see if it works but still not
}
-(void)startAnimating
{
    [_indicatorView startAnimating];
}
-(void)stopAnimating
{
    [_indicatorView stopAnimating];
}

/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
}
*/

@end
```

And I am using this as:

```
_spinner = [[IndicatorView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160, 240, 80, 80)];
    [self.view addSubview:_spinner];
[_spinner startAnimating];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `bounds` because you are doing it relative to the inner rect.
`_indicatorView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];`
change to
`_indicatorView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];`